# Will inlining help into my executable reduce loading/execution speed?

Tags: c, performance

I have written a program written in C intended for command-line use and expected to be frequently use interspersed into shell-scripts has specialized help which cannot be served by `man` or `info` since it heavily uses ANSI escape sequences for colours.

The help as plain text including the escape sequences weighs 18.7 KiB. The executable with it inlined as a zero-terminated string (and an `if` clause to display it upon request) weighs 39.0 KiB and without it weighs 19 KiB. (No optimization or debugging options at compiling.)

I was thinking of inlining the help into the executable to make it easy for users to access it rather than having to remember a separate file name and location to `cat` to their terminal. (The executable will be in the shell search path so that's not an issue there.)

But I am concerned that the doubling will reduce the loading/execution speed.

OTOH I seem to have read/heard that the OS will cache the loaded executable so I need not worry much about this.

Another option is to make another separate `-help` executable (which weighs 28 KiB but which I don't need to worry about since it's not frequent use).

Are there any best practices for this kind of situation? Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: Don't worry about such details, a few Kb (or even Mb) more or less won't make any noticeable change. Focus rather on the algorithms you're useing.

Comment: For the amount of text (a few KiB) you're describing, the difference in loading/execution speed will be insignificant, unless you are using some very old/slow hardware.    I wouldn't bet on that being true if you are using a unix.  If you are using such hardware, do testing to determine if the effect is significant at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have nothing to worry about.

Linux uses demand paging for executables. That means when the executable is first launched, nothing is read from disk. Only when a page fault occurs (meaning the program tried to access memory which is not yet present) are the pages actually read from disk.

Some binaries written in Go are *tens of megabytes* in size and have no noticeable startup latency.

I encourage you to actually *try* each approach and benchmark the startup delay.

Comment: Jonathan, many call and jmp addresses are relative to where the exe is loaded in memory. How are these resolved with demand paging?

Comment: Paul, I'm not sure what you're getting at. Let's say the program is loaded at 1000 and libfoo is loaded at 4000. The calls to libfoo can still be calculated, even though libfoo isn't actually present in RAM. From the perspective of userspace demand-paging doesn't even exist; it is transparent.

Comment: Assume a non-demand paging system and a (small) executable is loaded into memory. Are there adresses that the loader needs to fix before the executable can run? If so, in demand-paging a page gets loaded into (virtual) memory - does the paging loader fix addresses in this page (that it got from the exe on disk)?

Comment: I understand your question now. You're asking how/when relocations are applied. Depmand paging is implemented by the kernel, while dynamic loading is implemented in user-space. So demand paging doesn't really affect that part of the load process. It does invert the problem though: I believe the application of relocations causes pages to be faulted in before they're executed / accessed by the program. I'm sure there are optimizations to avoid this. I'll have to look for a reference.

Comment: So your answer to this question should have been "dynamic loading" and the address fix-ups are applied by the dynamic loader. Once loaded, the demand-paging of the kernel takes over. Though they need to work in concert: a non-loaded (never-loaded) page must first be fixed-up and a paged-out page can just be reloaded (paged-in).

Comment: This conversation is starting to get a bit broad. Demand paging is just a natural function of virtual memory in Linux, and pages (from files or from nothing) are mapped into a process' virtual memory space with `mmap`.

Comment: When you run a dynamic executable on Linux, the kernel reads the ELF header and sees that it is requesting an interpreter (the dynamic linker/loader e.g. `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`). Instead of loading the executable, the kernel invokes the loader (itself a necessarily statically-linked executable), passing it the path of the file to be executed. `ld.so` then proceeds to `mmap` load segments of the executable into memory, then performs relocations as required. At all times, it's up to the kernel whether or not a given page is actually present in RAM or not.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your in-depth research. So a not-yet paged-in (loaded) page generates a page-fault and because the page isn't in the swap-file, control is given to ld which loads (`mmap`) the page and does the fix-ups, then returns control to the kernel which transfes control to the now loaded page. An already loaded but paged-out page is just paged-in by the kernel.

Comment: Not quite. `mmap()` says "pages from this file should be visible in virtual memory". Whether or not they have actually been read from disk into RAM is up to the kernel. Only the kernel handles page faults.  `ld.so` first dictates what should be loaded where, and the kernel makes it so.  There is no back-and-forth between the kernel and `ld.so` like you've described.